# CSS Animation Value interpolated in 2-step function

Tags: css

I want to use a simple blinking animation for something that should resemble a cursor and i just did an animation where the opacity goes from 0 to 1 with a step function infinite.

But for some reason it does not change between 0 and 1, but between 0 and 0.5-ish, i want it white on black as the text, but its grey on black. Am i not understanding animations, or is this weird behaviour? Or is there a better way to do it?

```css
body{
  background: black;
  color:white;
}

.cursor::after{
  content: "";
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c1::after{
 animation: cursorblink 1s steps(2) infinite;
}
 
.c2::after{
  animation: cursorblink2 1s steps(2) infinite;
}
 
@keyframes cursorblink{
  0% {opacity:0}
}

@keyframes cursorblink2{
  0% {opacity:0}
  100% {opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<span class="cursor c1"></span> <span class="cursor reference"></span>  <span class="cursor c2"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `steps()` is supposed to work. it's not very intuitive but what you need is one step and make the `opacity: 0` at `50%` (`0%` and `100%` will by default be `opacity: 1`

```css
body{
  background: black;
  color:white;
}

.cursor::after{
  content: "";
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.2rem;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c1::after,
.c2::after{
 animation: cursorblink 1s steps(1) infinite;
}
 

@keyframes cursorblink{
  50% {opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<span class="cursor c1"></span> 
<span class="cursor reference"></span>  
<span class="cursor c2"></span>
```

Comment: You sure right, thats not really intuitive haha. Thank you! So i guess im just not understanding it, i might start reading the docs on this one.